# python pandas and matplotlib installation conflict

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.5, data-science

I am using a Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 and I am trying to practice data science with python on my laptop. I am using python 3.5.1 on a virtualenv however when I install pandas and matplotlib seems like both of them are having a conflict when trying to be imported. Both has same error and the output is:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
    encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 559, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/deanarmada/.virtualenvs/python3-data-science/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 487, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

before accessing python through terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect answer on my own question would be to

add:
export LC_ALL=C
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

on you ~/.bash_profile

exit your terminal and then start again then you can now try importing everything